# Optimizing slow performing greatest-n-per-group query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table:

```
id | query   | update_date | website_id | device  | page    | impressions | clicks | position | is_brand
---+---------+-------------+------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+----------+---------
1  | kitchen | 2018-05-01  | 2          | desktop | http... | 11000       | 50     | 3        | 1
2  | table   | 2018-05-01  | 2          | desktop | http... | 7000        | 40     | 3        | 0
3  | kitchen | 2018-05-02  | 2          | desktop | http... | 11500       | 55     | 3        | 1
4  | table   | 2018-05-02  | 2          | desktop | http... | 7100        | 35     | 3        | 0
```

In this table I need a procedure that for each unique query gives me the best performing row in regards to clicks for a given time period. This resulted in the following procedure:

```
create or alter procedure get_best_website_querys
    @from as date,
    @to as date,
    @website_id as int
as
begin
    WITH    cte
          AS (SELECT    *
              ,         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY query ORDER BY clicks DESC) RN
              FROM      search_console_query
              where 
                update_date >= @from and 
                update_date <= @to and 
                website_id = @website_id 
             )
    SELECT  cte.id
     ,      cte.query
     ,      cte.update_date
     ,      cte.website_id
     ,      cte.device
     ,      cte.page
     ,      cte.impressions
     ,      cte.clicks
     ,      cte.POSITION
     ,      cte.is_brand
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   RN = 1
end;
```

Now, this works and gives me the correct result. My problem is that this table grows quite large and this query performs rather slowly (> 3 minutes for a year). The query gives the following execution plan:

[image]

On the table I have a non-clustered index on `clicks` and a clustered one on `(website_id, update_date)`.

I would like some input in regards to what would be the best approach to getting this to perform better. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Index on the column `query` might help.

Comment: Have you tried adding an index on `query, clicks` (in that order)?

Comment: Also use `SET NOCOUNT ON` after `BEGIN`.

Comment: I would try creating a non clustered index on `query` and another one on `clicks`.

Answer (score 2):

First, try adding an index on `search_console_query scq(website_id, update_date, query, clicks)`.

Then would suggest trying this version:

```
select scq.*
from search_console_query scq
where scq.update_date >= @from and 
      scq.update_date <= @to and 
      scq.website_id = @website_id and
      scq.clicks = (select max(scq2.clicks)
                    from search_console_query scq2
                    where scq2.website_id = scq.website_id and
                          scq2.query = scq.query and
                          scq2.update_date >= @from and
                          scq2.update_date <= @to
                    );
```

This version can take advantage of two indexes:  `search_console_query(website_id, query, update_date, clicks)` and `search_console_query(website_id, update_date, query, clicks)`.

This is slightly different, because it will return multiple rows for a query in the event of ties.  If the performance improves significantly -- and this is an issue -- then that can be fixed.

EDIT:

The easiest way to remove duplicates for the second version is to assume that the table has a unique `id` column:

```
select scq.*
from search_console_query scq
where scq.update_date >= @from and 
      scq.update_date <= @to and 
      scq.website_id = @website_id and
      scq.sqc_id = (select top (1) sqc2.id
                    from search_console_query scq2
                    where scq2.website_id = scq.website_id and
                          scq2.query = scq.query and
                          scq2.update_date >= @from and
                          scq2.update_date <= @to
                    order by scq2.clicks desc);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've made a clustered index ``(website_id, update_date, query, clicks)`` instead of the original one, as well as one on ``query`` and one one ``(query, clicks)``.. Your query however outperforms the original one by a lot. There is many duplicate rows however. Is this something that can be fixed without sacrificing too much performance?

Comment: @FrederikHansen see if your original query is able to use this index.

Comment: @SalmanA The execution plan says that it is using this index, but the performance still isn't very good.

Comment: @FrederikHansen . . . See the edit using `order by` and `top`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the indexes suggested above. Secondly, parameter sniffing could also be happening here. I would suggest that you re-declare the variables inside the stored procedure as follows so that parameter sniffing doesn't happen:

```
create or alter procedure get_best_website_querys    
    @from as date,
    @to as date,
    @website_id as int
as
begin
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE = @from
       ,@EndDate AS DATE = @to
       ,@WebsiteID AS INT = @website_id

      WITH    cte
      AS (SELECT    *
          ,         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY query ORDER BY clicks DESC) RN
          FROM      search_console_query
          where 
            update_date >= @StartDate and 
            update_date <= @EndDate and 
            website_id = @WebsiteID
         )
SELECT  cte.id
 ,      cte.query
 ,      cte.update_date
 ,      cte.website_id
 ,      cte.device
 ,      cte.page
 ,      cte.impressions
 ,      cte.clicks
 ,      cte.POSITION
 ,      cte.is_brand
FROM    cte
WHERE   RN = 1
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like all of the columns in the select clause are *indexable*; you can try creating a massive covering index using included columns:

```
CREATE INDEX TEST_0001 ON search_console_query (
    website_id,
    update_date,
    query,
    clicks
) INCLUDE (
    id,
    device,
    page,
    impressions,
    position,
    is_brand
)
```

While you are at it, try more variations below and see which one is chosen by SQL server, then delete unnecessary ones:

- changing the order of `website_id, update_date`
- moving `query, clicks` inside included columns

Comment: So I made the 3 indexes and it seems to prefer the last one ( with ``query, clicks`` inside include). Should I alter my clustered index in regards to this information? Also, my performance didn't increase by much. As I see it my only option is to upgrade my database. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: I would not alter the clustered index. Also SQL server should not hit the table and .fetch the results directly from the index (the execution plan should will tell). That I think should be as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative way to do this. But not sure about the performance, typically this pattern is used to find the latest record with non grouped columns in select list.

```
SELECT          a.id,
                a.query,
                a.update_date,
                a.website_id,
                a.device,
                a.page,
                a.impressions,
                a.clicks,
                a.POSITION,
                a.is_brand
FROM            search_console_query a
LEFT JOIN       search_console_query b  ON b.website_id = a.website_id
                                       AND a.query = b.query
                                       AND a.clicks > b.clicks
WHERE           update_date >= @from
                AND update_date <= @to
                AND website_id = @website_id
                AND b.clicks IS NULL
```